# Matrix product notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, products

My lecturer has used some notation that I've never seen before: it is a (matrix) product symbol with a left-to-right arrow over the top. Does anybody know what this means?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could upload it as an image... to see what it actually looks like

Comment: $\vec{\times}$? And why did you add the tag `infinite-product`?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind when reading the question... i guess that symbol would like this:

$$\prod^{\rightarrow}$$

which makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Tolaso - I can't upload an image because I don't know what it's called! I've googled for it and read through the LaTeX wikibooks but as yet to no avail.

Comment: @xavierm02 & wltrup - I added the tag infinite-product because it was specifically an infinite product in the notes; I thought this may be relevant to specify which notation is being used. It's not a vector. It's a product.

Comment: The arrow is not straight like vector notation, it is curved over the top of the product symbol. But it's quite close to what @Tolaso has written.

Comment: @Ziggy perhaps you can upload a picture of the symbol from you notes. Also, what class was this in? That might help narrow things down

Comment: Yeah, @Ziggy I agree... you should upload an image to get a look of what it is like... It is not difficult. Just scan it from your notes and copy it here :)

Comment: Have you looked at [list of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) and/or at [list of mathematical symbols by subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject)?

Comment: @Ziggy The subject is statistics?

Comment: I think the simplest answer is to ask your lecturer what he/she means by it.

Comment: @Tolaso not statistics. It was really just linear algebra.

Comment: @wltrup that's probably fair.

Comment: For whatever it's worth: you can format the symbol as `\prod^\curvearrowright` to get
$$
\prod^\curvearrowright
$$
not sure how to add the indices in there though

Comment: @Omnomnomnom `\overset{\curvearrowright}{\prod^{k}}` produces $$
\overset{\curvearrowright}{\prod^{k}}$$

Answer (score 7):

The arrow notation removes ambiguity when certain procedures are represented by successive matrix multiplication.

For example, we can find [$LU$ decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) of the matrix $A$ by running [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on $A$. The reduced matrix is the upper triangular matrix $U$, where the reduction is represented by left multiplication of transformation matrices $E_i$ for $i \in\{1,\ldots, n-1\}$,

$$U = \left(\overset{\curvearrowleft}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}} E_i\right) A = E_{n-1}\cdots E_1 A.$$

Further, it can be shown that

$$L = \overset{\curvearrowright}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}} E_i^{-1} = E_1^{-1}\cdots E_{n-1}^{-1}$$

is a lower triangular matrix. Whence we obtain $A = LU$.

Not great for exposition, but fine as short hand.

Answer (score 6):

Matrix multiplication is not commutative, so (maybe) that symbol means that you are considering the product adding the next matrix to the right:
$$
X_1 X_2 \cdots X_k.
$$
Anyway, I am just guessing, I've never seen it before!

Answer (score 1):

The picture suggests that these are perhaps just two lines, which give
$$\curvearrowright \prod_{i=1}^k X_i=Y$$
if you write it in one line. Then it would mean that the equation $ \prod_{i=1}^k X_i=X_1X_2\cdots X_k=Y$ follows from another relation in the text before (i.e., $\cal{X} \curvearrowright \cal{Y})$.