# Symbol for the product of a series of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, products

I was searching for a product symbol like the ordinary $\prod$ but for matrices, where you can specify if the matrix-multiplication should be performed from the right or left. Something like:

$^{R}\prod_{i=1}^{3}M_{i}=M_{1}\cdot M_{2}\cdot M_{3}$

$^{L}\prod_{i=1}^{3}M_{i}=M_{3}\cdot M_{2}\cdot M_{1}$

Does somebody know anything like this?
Thanks in advance!

Sebastian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix product notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391874/matrix-product-notation)

Comment: Cool! Thanks! That is a nice way to represent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the notation from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391874/matrix-product-notation), as pointed out by @J.G. :

$$\overset{\curvearrowright}{\prod^3_{i=1}}M_i = M_1 \cdot M_2 \cdot M_3$$

and

$$\overset{\curvearrowleft}{\prod^3_{i=1}} M_i= M_3 \cdot M_2 \cdot M_1$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely not ever heard of any clear notational convention for this. You'll just need to annotate it, and explain as you've done here.

Comment: Of course, I can just define it, but I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel ;-) ... but I was a bit surprised, that it is apparently not commonly needed.

Comment: Indeed, just repeating, because of the non-commutativity, etc., I think there's no common convention. Sure, could-have-been, but, maybe not. So just explain your convention. At the very least, there's no powerful convention in opposition to what you propose. :)