# How to Represent this Matrix Product using $\prod$ Notation?

Tags: matrices, notation

I have the following matrix product :
$$
M^{(k-1)}\cdots M^{(2)}M^{(1)}A
\tag{1}$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $M_{k,k}^{(i)}$ are unit lower triangular $k\times k$ matrices for $i=1,2,\cdots k-1$.

My question is

> How can we represent $(1)$ using the $\displaystyle\prod$ notation?

Comment: Thank you, I was only afraid that these matrices do not commute.

Comment: Oh you are right, that would be a problem when writing it like that

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391874/matrix-product-notation) is a discussion about that.

Comment: Interesting notation! Thank you very much!!!